# Pdfjam ERROR: LaTeX package pdfpages.sty is not installed

Tags: 16.04, package-management, pdf, latex

Hi I've installed pdfjam for managing my pdf files, in order I've done this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pdfjam
```

Then I've tried this:

```
pdfnup --nup 2x2 1_Introduzione_nuova-26-2-2018.pdf
```

But I've got this output:

```
  pdfjam: This is pdfjam version 2.08.
  pdfjam: Reading any site-wide or user-specific defaults...
          (none found)
  pdfjam ERROR: LaTeX package pdfpages.sty is not installed
```

What should I do? I have Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=pdfpages.sty) you need to install `texlive-latex-recommended` package to get *pdfpages.sty*:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended
```